# Flex container moves off page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers

I'm having a problem with my flex container basically just leaving the page and going like this:

[image: image of an element out of the web page shown with inspect element]

I tried setting display to table and using `<td>` elements to put my things in, but it stayed out of the frame. I want it to be a flex container that will contain the first `<div>`, and the `<header>`s.

HTML:

```
<div class="presen">

        <div class="tisane"> <!--overlap d'images-->
            <img id="img1" src="images/herbal-tea-cup-png-images-35.png" alt="Tasse d'infusion de millepertuis" />
            <img id="img2" src="images/noircontourthe.png" alt="" />
        </div> 

        <header>

        </header>

    </div>
```

CSS of relevant elements:

```
      .tisane {
      display: inline-flex;

  }

  .tisane img#img1 {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 300px;
      height: 220px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 300px;
      left: 140px;
      z-index: 2;
  }

  .tisane img#img2 {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 330px;
      height: 230px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 298px;
      left: 130px;
      z-index: 1;
  }

  header h1 {
      text-align: center;
  }

  .presen {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      top: 298px;
      padding: 0;
      
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of your `body` and `presen` class.

```css
.tisane {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.tisane img#img1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 140px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tisane img#img2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 330px;
  height: 230px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  left: 130px;
  z-index: 1;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.presen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 298px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%; //The height of a flexbox can be also set to a percentage
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="presen">

    <div class="tisane"> <!--overlap d'images-->
        <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="Tasse d'infusion de millepertuis" />
        <img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="" />
    </div> 

    <header>

    </header>

</div>
```

Comment: I did this. Thanks! Though now the problem is instead of being inside of .presen, my image goes under it?

Comment: The problem with your CSS is that both your images are positioned as `absolute` and both your images are set to `top: 300` which makes the `#img2` to be placed below the first. I updated my post to demonstrate the problem.